# From a WCF service how can I call a method in a third party dll as the current user not IIS\DefaultApppool

Tags: wcf, impersonation, cyber-ark

I have a requirement to write a WCF service that will be called from MS Excel using the Service Moniker from VBA code. So far that part I have figured out.

I also have impersonation working so that if I were to return the current user from a web method it will return my username and not IIS\DefaultAppPool or whatever IIS is running as...

So here is my issue. I have a third party dll "CyberArk Password Management if anyone is interested" where I create a PWD object, set some parameters and then call a method named Getpassword. Now I can call the method but I always get a authenication failure. If I dig into the logs of the CyberArk agent that I have running it seems that even though I am using Impersonation that the dll method is still being called as IIS\DefaultAppPool

Here are a few snippets...

Impersonation is turned on at the method Level

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
```

A call to this method returns my Domain and User name as I would expect

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

But this line is being called as IIS\DefaultAppPool

```
password = PasswordSDK.GetPassword(passRequest);
```

I have tried doing Impersonation in Code rather than using the Annotaion, I have also tried a Impersonation object with a using bolck and nothing seems to work so here is what I am thinking.

1. The dll somehow does not allow me to impersonate the caller for security reasons
2. It may be the .NET framework not allowing this again for security reasons
3. I have no clue and would love some help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can [self-host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750530.aspx) the application instead of using IIS to host.  Then the service will be running in a process that is already running as the current user.

(If this an option)

Comment: You can also set IIS to run the application under a specificed account.

Comment: I may need more explanation...

This service has to reside on a server that has a particular software installed. For testing I have the "Agent" installed locally. Without the agent it will not work regardless.

If I were to do a self hosting service I assume that the Executable would reside on the end users machine correct? Then the service could reside on the machine with the agent installed.

I will try your suggestion and see what I come up with, just thought that might add some clarity to my problem.

Thanks